# Graphic driver Linux kernel 5.3 problem Ubuntu 19.10 AMD Ryzen

Tags: drivers, 19.10, amd-ryzen

I have problems probably with graphic drivers. I attach my screen. During using GNOME desktop and Firefox, I see blurred picture, but not all time only sometime.

When I used Ubuntu 19.04 everything was OK. I saw the same problem with Fedora and kernel 5.2. 
Windows 10 works OK.

I have Huawei MateBook 14D with AMD Ryzen 2500U.

[image: screenshot]

[image: blurred picture]

I coped amdgpu firmware as is described in https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-19.10-Radeon-RX-5700 and added Oibaf PPA and Ubuntu works OK.

Comment: We received 5.3 on 18.04 today and I started seeing this on my Ryzen 5 3400g with AMD Raven graphics.