# AMD graphic driver oibaf missing file

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu

I added ppa drivers ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers and after update I have missing file:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgp
u
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdg
```

I tried download linux-firmware and copy missing file but these files are not there.I updated due to problem with GNOME [Graphic driver Linux kernel 5.3 problem Ubuntu 19.10 AMD Ryzen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183701/graphic-driver-linux-kernel-5-3-problem-ubuntu-19-10-amd-ryzen)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an AMD video card?
I have Intel graphics and I had a similar (radeon) error using Padoka I assume it's because the AMD packages are not required for intel..?

Also Oibaf drivers are bleeding edge and can be unstable, I would use Padoka stable or x-swat
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates

Comment: I got: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu eoan Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83

Comment: they haven't made a release for Eoan yet, try Padoka unstable:
https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa/